# getItemLayout in React-Native FlatList

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am trying to use scrollToIndex function of react-native flatlist.
What I expect to be is a alphabet list view.
Too use scrollToIndex, I need to set getItemLayout prop of the flatlist component.
I have rendered items with the same alphabet as an item in the parent flatlist and rendered the items inside the children flatlists, so the item heights of the parent flatlist are varying.
The problem is that if I give getItemLayout prop, it gives me error like below.

Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: Should not have to estimate frames when a measurement metrics function is provided

```
<FlatList data={this.cityList}
    renderItem={this.renderCityGroup}
    style={styles.cityList}
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => item + index}
    getItemLayout={(data, index) => {
        return {
            length: data.height,
            offset: data.total
        }
    }}
    ref={ref => this.cityListRef = ref}
/>
```

This is my current code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your case, this is quite simple. Inside of the `data` are your items. So, if you didn't purposefully modify that array so it has a property `height` and `total`, this isn't going to work at all.

Adding to that, `offset` is not the total height of all elements, but the height of all elements summed up **which came before** the issued element.

Example:

React native requests it needs the item at index 3 and our items have a height of `10`, `20`, `30` and `40`

For the third element `offset` you need to add the "zeroth", the first and the second so you get the "starting y coordinate" (or x depends on what list direction is). For the `length` just pas the height of your element, which in our case would be 40.

Your final returning object should look something like this.

```
return {
  index: index,
  /*
    You need to implement the two functions below so they actually return
    what I described above.
  */
  length: getItemHeight(index),
  offset: getItemOffset(index),
}
```

If someone needs help with an implementaion leave a comment and I can give you a hint :).

There are some more pitfalls though. The react team has either made an error or somehow thinks it's funny (or it may be actually useful I have no idea) to sometimes ask for the element at index `-1` which, at least I, do not have. For this special case I prepend this code before the one I posted above:

```
// New, negative index preventing code
if (index === -1) return { index, length: 0, offset: 0 };
// Old code
return {
  index: index,
  length: getItemHeight(index),
  offset: getItemOffset(index),
}
```

**NOTE:** If your items all have the same height this whole calculation is **way** easier. I would just be:

```
return {
  index,
  length: itemHeight, // itemHeight is a placeholder for your amount
  offset: index * itemHeight,
};
```

Comment: Why we need to return index argument back?

Comment: @tejasvi88 don't remember, honestly, haven't done RN in a while. In case it's used by RN, well that's just how it is, otherwise you may omit it :)